# How do i solve this particular scenario using rxjs?

Tags: angular, rxjs

The problem i have a list of id's that i can load cheaply, loading details for each is more expensive.

So i want to load the entire list of 'id objects', subscribe to the stream fetch the first 5 and on a mouse click fetch the next 5(paging back and forth).

The resulting stream i will then make an xhr request for each item in the current batch.

```js
var clicks = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($nextPageButton, 'click')
var arrayObs = Observable.from([{id:3}, {id:2}, {id:1}, {id:6}, {id:5}, {id:4}]);
```

I have tried countless ways of mapping merging etc. Cant get the hang of it.

simple plunker

https://plnkr.co/edit/W83d3xftZv25YqhOF8uL?p=preview

Comment: can u please provide plunkr link/code details further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to only use observables, you can do as follow

```
let page = 0;
let size = 3;

let arrayObs = Observable.from([{id:3}, {id:2}, {id:1}, {id:6}, {id:5}, {id:4}]);

// Click observables that emit the page we want to display.
let clickPreviousObs = Observable.fromEvent(this.prevButton.nativeElement, 'click').map(() => {
  page--;
  return page;
});
let clickNextObs = Observable.fromEvent(this.nextButton.nativeElement, 'click').map(() => {
  page++;
  return page;
});

// Merge click observables so there is only one observable that emit the page, and start with the first page.
let pageObs = Observable.merge(clickPreviousObs, clickNextObs).startWith(page);

// When I get a new page, get the corresponding ids.
let resultObs = pageObs.flatMap((currentPage) => {
  console.log('Page ', currentPage);
  return arrayObs.skip(currentPage * size).take(size);
});

resultObs.subscribe((res) => {
  console.log('Result', res);
});
```

See [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/EpmVI8wQeq66hjk1DPiy?p=preview)